# glitch in numerical optimization in python using nelder-mead

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I am trying a two variable optimization of a non-linear function using the scipy.optimize.minimize module using the Nelder-Mead method. The optimization is quite successful overall but in between there is a sudden jump of values in the optimization variable and then onward the optimization parameter curve follows the same shape but with a dc shift. The image might be helpful in understanding my problem. I have played around with the function tolerance but in vain. The jump creates havoc in further programming. The images are [community edit to inline the images] here:

First, the optimization variable with the glitch:

[image: optimization variable with glitch]

Second, a zoom of the glitch:
[image: zoomed-in part of the glitch]

Third, the havoc that the first optimization variable causes in this second optimization variable exactly after the same point:

[image: resulting havoc]

The green dots are the expected optimization curves whereas the blue lines are the obtained optimization curves.

Comment: You will have to give what you are optimizing if you want any serious help. You might be falling into local minima, etc. Maybe try guessing a better starting point and check if the optimizer returns anything (like maximum iterations reached) etc.

Comment: @seberg :
ok, here's the entire project (If anyone wants to have a look): http://www.2shared.com/file/tibAQNc6/Coutaz-_Py.html
steps to run the project :
1) first run the "1st PROGRAM TO RUN.py" with appropriate changes in the path to the file at the lines 118,123,128. This will generate three text files which are read by the program "SECOND PROGRAM TO RUN.py". 
2) now run the program "SECOND PROGRAM TO RUN.py" . this is where the optimization takes place..... (please read the following comment for continuation)

Comment: ....this program initially reads a "configfile.txt" (make appt changes to its path, the configfile.txt is in the rar) which I have pre-configured to get the above ouput (the images). make appt changes in the path at line numbers 73,95,97,99. The minimization function is at line number 131 (the function at line 130 is the same function but for an another method called "NR_Powell" which accepts a different format of input variables). The 'error function' which is the minimization function has a sub function which is at line number 48

Comment: Stop Stop Stop. What is the mathematical formulation of the objective function? Are you doing minimization of a function of two variables? If so, why do we see graphs in 2D instead of a nifty 3D plot?

Comment: Yes I am doing minimization of a function in two variables (you can see the entitled "k2" and "n2" graphs which are the minimized variables). I am new to python and I don't know how to make a 3D plot